# In which file we add dependencies in gradle? Like while using maven we can add dependencies in pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have this code:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;@RequestMapping("/login")
```

After importing this, I get the error

> cannot resolve symbol requestMapping

I am not able to resolve this.
Could anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: Check whether the symbol `requestMapping` is defined in the scope where the error occured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add dependencies in build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```